# Hibernate FullTextSearch Exception at SessionInitialize

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I am trying to create fulltext indexes and take specific search result as list with Hibernate. 
I can not pass beyond session initialization.

Here is my code:

This is HibernateUtil Class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

This is the code I start FullTextSession:

```
try {
        fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SatisYonetimiEkrani.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

And this is the function where I want to make fulltext search:

```
private void aramaYap() {
    QueryBuilder productQb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Satislar.class).get();
    Query fullTextQuery = (Query) productQb.keyword().onField("musteriadi").matching("Ramazan").createQuery();

    List<Satislar> satis = fullTextQuery.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < satis.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(satis.get(i).getMusteriadi());
    }
}
```

I think I may have problems with my jar files. Here is list of jar files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your versions of Hibernate ORM (4.3) and Hibernate Search (5.5) don't match. Hibernate Search 5.5 is meant to be used with ORM 5.x (5.0.6 is the latest at this time).

Also you have Hibernate ORM *and* EclipseLink on your classpath, which at least for the spec packages (javax.persistence.*) gives you duplicated packages. Assuming you want to work with Hibernate Search, you should remote the EclipseLink JARs.

On a more general note, you will greatly benefit from using a dependency management tool such as Maven, Gradle or Ant+Ivy.

Comment: I have removed EclipseLink Jars and Hibernate ORM 4.3 libraries. But now I cant even build project. Now I m using using Hibernate 5.0.6. It does  not even build project. This is what i get : **'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'**

Comment: Seems like you still got some EclipseLink dependency somewhere.

Comment: It is not working without Eclipse libraries somehow. It works now but I dont how it works too. I was constanly deleting and importing jar files and it worked. now it works with Hibernate 5.0.6 but eclipse libraries are there too.

Comment: You have to remove the EclipseLink libraries, and also rewrite your HibernateUtil. That is not how you start a SessionFactory in Hibernate 5.