# Hibernate Transaction.wasRolledBack is not working

Tags: java, spring, swing, hibernate, jar

I have been trying to use hibernate on a java swing application. I want to add FullTextSearch feature to app.

I thought I have problems with my jar files and removed hibernate 4.3 jar files and started to use 5.0.6 hibernate version. But now `Transaction.wasRolledBack` functions in my code are not working. Here is my previous question about subject:

[Hibernate FullTextSearch Exception at SessionInitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404406/hibernate-fulltextsearch-exception-at-sessioninitialize/34406066#34406066)

My current jar setup is here:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by .wasRolledBack is not working? Does it produce the wrong result? Does it not work? Showing the code would help.

Comment: When I get back to Hibernate 4.3.x version wasRolledBack is working. But it does not work with 5.0.6. Same libraries but different version. It is not even deprecated. It gives cannot find symbol error. No wasRolledBack function exist in 5.0.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switched from Hibernate 4.3.1 to 5.0.6 and Transaction is gone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458125/switched-from-hibernate-4-3-1-to-5-0-6-and-transaction-is-gone)