# Switched from Hibernate 4.3.1 to 5.0.6 and Transaction is gone

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, jar, transactions

I am working on a Hibernate project.I had used Hibernate 4.3.1 libraries of Netbeans. Then I needed to use Apache Lucene for fulltext searching. To be able to use Lucene I needed to switch to Hibernate 5.x jars.I can define a new `Transaction` object but `wasRollecBack` method of `Transaction` class is not working. I used this method in several places and now I'm stuck. When I look at javadoc of Hibernate 5.0.6 there is nothing like `org.hibernate.transaction` . There is `org.hibernate.engine.transaction` but it does not work either.

When I get back to 4.3.1 `wasRolledBack` is working but this time I cant run project with lucene libraries. I am confused.

Comment: What do you mean by .wasRolledBack is not working?

Comment: Cannot find symbol. Seems it is not even there.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wasRolledBack` method is not included in the `Hibernate 5.0.6` version `Transaction` interface    [Here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/Transaction.java) .

`4.3.1` version that was taking place in the `wasRolledBack` method.

Existing methods:

```
public interface Transaction {

    void begin();

    void commit();

    void rollback();

    TransactionStatus getStatus();

    void registerSynchronization(Synchronization synchronization) throws HibernateException;

    void setTimeout(int seconds);

    int getTimeout();

    void markRollbackOnly();

 }
```

I did not test, but you can use the `getStatus` method.

Example:

```
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = session.getTransaction().getStatus();
    if(transactionStatus.equals(TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK)){
        //action s.a :)
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

*`TransactionStatus` Enum Constant and Description:*

> *ACTIVE* : The transaction has been begun, but not yet completed.
>
> *COMMITTED* : The transaction has been competed successfully.
>
> *COMMITTING* :Status code indicating a transaction that has begun the
>   second phase of the two-phase commit protocol, but not yet completed
>   this phase.
>
> *FAILED_COMMIT*:The transaction attempted to commit, but
>   failed.
>
> *MARKED_ROLLBACK*:The transaction has been marked for rollback only.
>
> *NOT_ACTIVE*:The transaction has not yet been begun
>
> *ROLLED_BACK*:The transaction has been rolled back.
>
> *ROLLING_BACK*:Status code indicating a transaction that is in the
>   process of rolling back.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit busy. I looked at your answer and It worked. I looked at javadoc but it seems i skipped enumeration thing. Thank you.